# websocket.onerror = function(evt) {...}; doesn't work in Chrome but works fine in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have an issue with the following code:

```
websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
alert('error');
};
```

the function works just fine in Firefox but it does absolutely nothing in Google Chrome!

Is there any specific way to do the same in chrome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onerror#Browser_compatibility Chrome is supported both on the Desktop and Mobile. Please run all updates to Chrome and make sure you have no other errors in the console. I hope this helps.

Comment: How did you test this?